# KeyError: 0 from Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to follow chapter 3 of Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow for classification of MNIST data. The command runs as follows in Jupyter notebook:

```
>>> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
>>> mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
>>> mnist.keys()
dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'feature_names', 'DESCR', 'details',
'categories', 'url'])

>>> X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
>>> X.shape
(70000, 784)
>>> y.shape
(70000,)
```

The following command throws error

```
>>> some_digit = X[0]
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-348a6e96ae02> in <module>
----> 1 some_digit = X[0]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3456             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3457                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3458             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3459             if is_integer(indexer):
   3460                 indexer = [indexer]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 0
```

It is hard for me understand what the actual error is as I have not come across similar one for such a simple assignment. What is causing the issue?

Comment: What is `X`? A `pandas.DataFrame`? If so, why are you trying to index into it and what do you expect it to return?

Comment: `X` is a `pandas.DataFrame`. The actual assignment is done above way in the book as well. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X` is a dataframe so if you use `X[0]`, it means you are looking for a column named "0". If you want the first row (index) of your dataframe, you have to use `.loc` or `.iloc`. In your case both methods are equivalent (only) because the index is numeric, start from 0 and continuous:

```
# Extract the first row as a Series
>>> X.loc[0]
pixel1      0.0
pixel2      0.0
pixel3      0.0
pixel4      0.0
pixel5      0.0
           ... 
pixel780    0.0
pixel781    0.0
pixel782    0.0
pixel783    0.0
pixel784    0.0
Name: 0, Length: 784, dtype: float64

# Extract a pixel by label
>>> X.loc[0, 'pixel7']
0.0

# Extract the same pixel by position
>>> X.iloc[0, 6]
0.0
```

**Update**

> Probably iloc would be more appropriate here

If you want to use `iloc`, prefer use `numpy` instead of `pandas` and convert `data` and `target` columns as array:

```
X, y = mnist["data"].to_numpy(), mnist["target"].to_numpy()
```

Comment: Thanks. Probably `iloc` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: I updated my answer related to your comment.